# stuck to when get ACRA bug report?

Tags: android, google-docs, acra

I need to send the bug report into  `GoogleDocs`  `CrashReports-Template`.
But I am not getting a single error.

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "dfbhkdfjbnkjsdnkjsdfn")
public class MainActivity extends Application
{
 @Override
   public void onCreate()
   {
      super.onCreate();
      ACRA.init(this);
   }     
}
```

any suggestion?
where am I wrong?

Comment: Don't you forget to add internet permission and set application class into manifest?

Comment: @Dimmerg : I already done this thing

Comment: Which version of ACRA do you use?

Comment: @Dimmerg : acra-4.5.0 version .... I have a doubt, @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "dfbhkdfjbnkjsdnkjsdfn") this line is only need to get the error in the CrashReports-Template in GoogleDocs Form.

Comment: You can read my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not use GoogleForms, because developers of ACRA strongly not recommend this. You can read more here https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Notice-on-Google-Form-Spreadsheet-usage and also note on this:

> Unfortunately, we have been asked by Google to stop making our users
>   automatically post data to Google Forms just before the 'refresh' of
>   this great tool published a few months ago. The current
>   GoogleFormSender is working only on 'Legacy Forms'which can't be
>   created anymore in Google Drive.

So, I think will better to change your reports transporting into other destination:
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#reports-destination

Comment: so , should I go with ACRA or some other tool ?

Comment: Of course, you still can use ACRA, but you should switch to other reports destination. For example, you can send reports to email or write your own server script and send reports to this script. Also, you can copy, deploy to your server and use default ACRA backend & frontend - https://github.com/ACRA/acra-storage and https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer

Comment: I downloaded both things but how can I use in my application for get the bug report ...

Comment: These things used on server. I think for you will better to use sending reports on mail - it's simple to implement and use.
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-by-email

Comment: I did this thing through mail and API but can't understand the meaning of ACRA backend and frontend but thanks for the help sir, I remove some confusion by your post ... thanks again

Comment: If you have working on the ACAR backend or frontend , please give a brief idea... even I use mail for the bug report but I can't leave this topic without the mean of ACRA frontend and Backend :)

Comment: I didn't work yet, but I think it works so:
1) you have your own server or virtual server
2) you are downloading ACRA backend and frontend and deploy it into your server
3) you are setting your app's ACRA to work with your server backend
4) you working with reports using frontend.

Unfortunately, I didn't use them before, so I can't provide you more details

Comment: thanks for the explanation .... this really help me for understanding the mean of frontend and backend

Comment: According to your answer ... what is the difference b/w the API ang ACRA backend ??

Answer (score 0):

Sending crash reports to Google Docs isn't supported anymore. Google wasn't happy about this usage. You can find the alternatives [in the documentation](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Notice-on-Google-Form-Spreadsheet-usage).

Comment: sir , do you have any idea for using the ACRA frontend or backend for getting the bug report :  https://github.com/ACRA/acra-storage and https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer